# Results Fetched from Mysql DB Stay on Page

Tags: php, mysql

I m fetching a table from mysql using php the result is displayed as an array on the html page the result stays on the page even if i refresh the page or if i fetch a new record it adds to the end of the previous result

please guide me that the result is removed on page refresh or if a new row is ordered it must replace the previous one
here's the code

```
<div id="outPut">
    <form id="sUserb" name="Output" action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="SELECT" name="sUser"></form>
    <div id="sUser">
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['sUser'])) {
            $oMySQL = new MySQL('library', 'root', '', 'localhost');
            $where = array('bID' => '0');
            echo "<pre>";
            $result = $oMySQL->Select('user', $where);
            print_r($result);
            echo "</pre>";
            foreach ($result as $key => $val) {
                foreach ($val as $label => $item) {
                    echo $label . "====" . $item . "<br >";
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Regards

Comment: No one can guide you unless and until you throw the relevant code here

Comment: code code code code where is da code?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it obvious that the result stays on the page? Every time you refresh the page, the query gets executed and spits out the content of the table on the page.

Comment: how to get rid of this

Comment: technically redesign your webpage/application. Why showing this data to the user only once? Perhaps keeping track with session so you don't perform the DB call in case the user has a session running

Comment: how to clear the one time fetched result from the div in the code